# Error Message Inline with Input

Tags: php, arrays, forms, error-handling

> This is my code for error function

```
function output_errors($errors) {
    return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
}
```

> This is my php code for login

```
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
      $errors[] = 'Enter a valid username or password.';
    }
      elseif (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'User does not exist.';
      }
      elseif (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Please activate your account first.';
      }
      else {

        if (strlen($password) > 32) {
          $errors[] = 'Password too long. <br>';
        }

        $login = login($username, $password);

        if ($login === false) {
          $errors[] = 'Incorrect username or password.';
        }
          else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login; //login returns user_id  
            header('Location: hashtagphotowall.php');
            exit();
          }
        }

    //visual representation of error arrays
    //print_r($errors);

}
  else {
    $errors[] = 'No data received!';
  }

if (empty($errors) === false) {
  echo output_errors($errors);
}
```

> This is my html code for login form

```
<div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
     <p class="modal-row"><em>Sign In.</em><hr></p>
     <a href="#" class="button small">Connect with Facebook</a>
     <p class="hr-enclosed">or login with email</p>

     <form action="login.php" method="post">
       <div class="field-box">
         <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username:" />
         <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password:" />
         <input type="submit" name="loginbutton" class="button small" value="LOGIN" />                      
       </div>
     </form>

   <p class="modal-row-sub">forgot your password? get help <a href="#">here</a>.<br>new user? sign up <a href="#" data-reveal-id="secondModal">here</a>.</p>
   <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

> The code is functioning but the error messages display on another webpage. I tried declaring a variable with no value and echo it inline with the input tag but I have no output. Maybe it's because I use the error arrays incorrectly. Any help on how can I make error arrays inline with the **input tags** in the login form? **THANK YOU**

Comment: Are the brackets balanced correctly? `if (empty($_POST) === false) { `... `else {
    $errors[] = 'No data received!';
  }`  Is that the right logic?  Shouldn't there be a choice.. if no errors go to new page, if errors, redisplay the form and tell user what to fix...

Comment: Yes, it is balanced. And the code is working. I just added the 'no data received.' The problem here is I don't know how to display the error message inline with the html input tags.

Comment: Is your *html form* and the *login script* on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the test logic built into the same login.php file as the form is displayed.  That way it makes passing of data back to user easier.

(pseudo code)

```
Add a div to the top of the form: `<div id="errors">output_errors($errors) </div>` 
which tells user what to do.  Obviously first time thru $errors = "" (or one space?)  
The error div will be invisible to the user.

If previous submission made, test the data for validity.

If previous submission is made and input is good, go on to new page
 (Success_thank_you_for_your_submission.php)

If previous submission is made, and input is not valid, 
redisplay the page, only now the errors will be on top of the form.
redisplay with header("location:[login.php]");

You should take the time to re-populate all the fields the user originally submitted.
Sending back an empty form when there are errors won't make folks happy.
```

User keeps submitting form till its right...

Answer (score 0):

Modify your php login validation and checking code:

```
if (empty($errors) === false) {
  // store error details into the session variable
  $_SESSION['validation_errors'] = $errors;
  // then redirect back to login page.
  header('Location: login_page.php');
}
```

On your login form, move the output_errors() function inside it.

```
function output_errors($errors) {
    echo '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
}
```

Then add this code to your login form. This is where the errors will be shown (usually before the form):

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['validation_errors'])): ?>
<div class="validation_error_box">
  <?php output_errors($_SESSION['validation_errors']); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

BONUS: If the login credentials are invalid, you can add the username into the $_SESSION array then display it back on the login page.